# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x' in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pgzero

I'm working on a basic game with python, but the system gives an error

impostors.x = new_x_pos
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x'

Below is my code, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've checked very carefully but still can't find the error, Since I'm a newbie, I don't have much experience so I hope you guys can help me

```
import pgzrun
import random

FONT_COLOR = (255, 255, 255) #màu RGB
WIDTH = 1300
HEIGHT = 700
CENTER_X = WIDTH / 2
CENTER_Y = HEIGHT / 2
CENTER = (CENTER_X, CENTER_Y)
START_SPEED = 10
COLORS = ["orange", "blue"]
current_level = 1
final_level = 5
game_over = False
game_complete = False
impostors = []
animation = []

def draw():
    global impostors,current_level,game_over,game_complete
    screen.clear()
    screen.blit("dark",(0,0))
    if game_over:
        display_message("Game Over", "Press Space to play again")
    elif game_complete:
        display_message("You win", "Press Space to play again")
    else:
        for im in impostors:
            im.draw()

def update():
    global impostors,current_level,game_over,game_complete
    if len(impostors) == 0:
        impostors = make_impostors(current_level)
    if (game_over or game_complete) and keyboard.space:
        impostors = []
        current_level = 1
        game_complete = False
        game_over = False

def make_impostors(number_of_impostors):
    colors_to_create = get_colors_to_create(number_of_impostors)
    new_impostors = create_impostors(colors_to_create)
    layout_impostors(new_impostors)
    animate_impostors(new_impostors)
    return new_impostors

def get_colors_to_create(number_of_impostors):
    colors_to_create = ["red"]
    for i in range(0,number_of_impostors):
        random_color = random.choice(COLORS)
        colors_to_create.append(random_color)
    return colors_to_create

def create_impostors(colors_to_create):
    new_impostors = []
    for color in colors_to_create:
        impostor = Actor(color + "-im")
        new_impostors.append(impostors)
    return new_impostors

def layout_impostors(impostors_to_layout):
    number_of_gaps = len(impostors_to_layout) + 1
    gap_size = WIDTH/number_of_gaps
    random.shuffle(impostors_to_layout)
    for index, impostor in enumerate(impostors_to_layout):
        new_x_pos = (index + 1)*gap_size
        impostor.x = new_x_pos

def animation_impostors(impostors_to_animate):
    for impostors in impostors_to_animate:
        duration = START_SPEED - current_level
        impostors.anchor = ("center", "bottom")
        animation = animation(impostors, duration = duration, on_finished = handle_game_over, y = HEIGHT)
        animations.append(animation)

def handle_game_over():
    global game_over
    game_over = True

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    global impostors, current_level
    for impostors in impostors:
        if impostors.collidepoint(pos):
            if "red" in impostors.image:
                red_impostor_click()
            else:
                handle_game_over()

def red_impostor_click():
    global current_level, impostors, animation, game_complete
    stop_animations(animations)
    if current_level == final_level:
        game_complete = True
    else:
        current_level = current_level + 1
        impostors = []
        animations = []

def stop_animations(animations_to_stop):
    for animation in animations_to_stop:
        if animation.running:
            animation.stop()

def display_message(heading_text, sub_heading_text):
    screen.draw.text(heading_text, fontsize = 60, center = CENTER, color = FONT_COLOR)
    screen.draw.text(sub_heading_text,
    fontsize = 30,
    center = (CENTER_X, CENTER_Y + 30),
    color = FONT_COLOR)

pgzrun.go()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the loop `for impostors in impostors:`. Rename the loop variable to `impostor:`

```py
def on_mouse_down(pos):
    global impostors, current_level
    for impostor in impostors:
        if impostor.collidepoint(pos):
            if "red" in impostors.image:
                red_impostor_click()
            else:
                handle_game_over()
```